# Stack Overflow List Header Gigantic

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

I use a bookmark to list things I'm interested in participating in as:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+-wordpress*+-laravel*+-symfony*+-codeigniter*+-yii2*+-tinybutstrong*+-drupal*+-smarty*`

So, a couple of weeks ago, Stack Overflow page results started looking like this:

[image: Good grief guys/gals]

And so I used [Adblock Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock_Plus) to block element `stackoverflow.com##.grid--cell.fl1.fs-headline1.mb24`. That worked for a couple of weeks. Now, today, all of a sudden, the page is now doing this:

[image: Good grief guys/gals, take 2]

And yes, I used Adblock Plus again to remove that new `stackoverflow.com##.mb24`.

So what is my question?

**Is there some on-site solution to remove this?** So I do not have to resort to using Adblock Plus, which also blocks your normal ads along with these unwieldy blocks of info?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. Are you sure you are not using any custom CSS or something of the sort?

Comment: See if it shows you that blob of tags if you use the bookmark I use (added to top of my question).

Comment: Interesting.  The search URL you provide has wildcards in the tags, which explains the multiples of all the wordpress version tags.

Comment: Yeah. I did that a while back because of the sea of wordpress questions with sub-tags. So I wildcarded it. Worked great.... but when the header started showing them ALL, it began to be this problem in my screenshots. I could remove them all, but then I'm back to a sea of wordpress (and others) that I really don't like bothering with.

Comment: Also, because of how many `wordpress*` tags exist, I get a 404 if I try to click the search button from the auto-filled search field.  I'm guessing we're way beyond the max length for the search input box.

Comment: @ryanyuyu oh, wow, you are right. I never did click that button after doing this. I sure have overloaded the tag exclusions didn't I? Maybe I need to not be so picky. Hmm. Well... maybe this will spawn into a feature request to have better generic handling of wildcard search exclusions/additions.

Comment: this was just *fixed* https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311239/dont-put-the-searched-tags-on-top-of-stackoverflow#311239

Comment: @rene ... ok, then I guess I disagree with the 'fix' ;) Well, ok it IS better than a giant block of bold text (I'll give them that). However, its still way too much info. Shame they didnt put it in a height limited box with a css toggle to 'show all' if a user wants too see all the tags if its more than 1 row of them.

Comment: All true, but for now I'm already happy these major annoyances get somewhat squashed in 6 to 8 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know, if you add all these tags to your ignored tags list and then set ignored tags to "hidden" in your profile settings, you don't need to exclude them, they will just not show up at all when you search for [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php).

Comment: Technically they will just not show up at all. Full stop. It isn't only when you search for PHP. That would be hilarious though.

Comment: @TinyGiant PHP is mentioned in the context of OP's question; he's searching for PHP questions that aren't tagged with any of those other 500 tags.

Comment: This does elegantly solve my issue with the mass of 'not' tags at the top. By adding them as wildcards to my general ignore list, it presents the same search results (new bookmark) with less tag overload at the top.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with this `userContent.css` style for Firefox to remove the original gargantuan heading:

```
@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {
  div#mainbar > div.grid > h1.mb24 {
    visibility: hidden !important;
    height: 0px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
  }
}
```

With a slight adjustment it could be made to hide the new tag list as well:

```
@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {
  div#mainbar .mb24 {
    visibility: hidden !important;
    height: 0px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
  }
}
```

or (if you just want the tag list removed and heading left in place):

```
@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {
  div#mainbar > div.mb24 {
    visibility: hidden !important;
    height: 0px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
  }
}
```

BTW, didn't this tag list used to be in the right sidebar? I don't quite see why anybody would consider it a good idea to move it to the top center of the page ...

Comment: It's a search result, not a tag list.

Comment: Right, I have my normal 'favorite tags' seen in the right side bar. But anti-tags are not favorites it seems haha. This is a good solution for firefox users. Sadly I've migrated away from firefox for awhile now and have fully sold my sole to google.

Comment: @Catija The search result is a list of tags (otherwise it wouldn't say "Tagged with", would it?). And like I said, I seem to recall that this exact same thing used to be in the right sidebar (and I don't mean the favorite tags list)